# Changing program execution flow by signal and return address

Tags: c++, g++, signals, callstack, activation-record

I'm trying to change program execution flow by changing return address of functions in this code:

```
void s(int signum) {
    int b = 1;
    *(&b+3) = *(&b+3) + 4;
}

void f() {
    while(true);
    printf("f exit\n");
}

int main() {
    signal( SIGCONT, s );

    f();

    printf("end of prog");

    return 0;
}
```

For this purpose I invoke `f` function. So it gets stuck at `while(true)`. Then I send a `SIGCONT` signal to program using `kill -SIGCONT <PID>` command. Now the program must interrupt executing `while(true)` in `f` and execute `s` function. In `s` function I defined `b` to find return address of `s` function in runtime stack which is `*(&b+3)`. I try to change this value with `*(&b+3) = *(&b+3) + 4` so that when it gets back to `f`, skip execution of `while(true)` and execute `printf("f exit\n")`. but it keeps getting stuck at `while` and I have no idea how to make this work.

NOTE: I verified *(&b+3) as return address by comparing it to value returned by __builtin_return_address(0) before.

Body of functions `main` and `f` must be unchanged.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it this way? You could use a more portable approach, such as `setjmp(3)` / `longjmp(3)` or use a flag in the signal handler.

Comment: The return address of `s` is not within `f` — it's in whatever runtime function is dispatching the signal.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a branch fault when a SIGCONT enters. The program must get stuck at `while(true)` until the signal comes and executes `s`. Then `s` should make it by changing its return address. By default the return address of `s` is `while(true)` in `f` and I want to change it to somewhere else like `printf("f exit\n");`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is tell somehow the while loop that something changed.
For example

```
volatile int flag = 0 ;

void s(int signum) {
    int b = 1;
    __sync_fetch_and_add( &flag, 1 ) ;
}

void f() {
    while(__sync_fetch_and_add( &flag, 0 ) == 0);
    printf("f exit\n");
}
```

The atomic intrinsic (function __sync_fetch_and_add) is added to avoid having the loop optimized away. I am not sure a simple volatile is enough. Waiting for comments myself on this....

Comment: Just make `flag` a `volatile sig_atomic_t` instead of `volatile int`. Then you can change its value without built-in, platform dependent functions.

Comment: Dear marom. Thanks for your answer. but I want to make this only by changing `s` return address to simulate a branch fault. So I want to do this without changing body of `f` and `main`.